# Latex "Curved Border"

Tags: latex

Can someone tell me how to create a "curved border" with latex, like in this example

[image: here]

Original Link see here: https://www.ulisses-spiele.de/assets/download/oldcontent/Staetten-okkulter-Geheimnisse_Bonusmaterial_Ecliptifactus-Umbraporta-LCD_d01e.pdf

You can see that the border follows the lines of the background image.

Or at least tell me for what I have to look for...
So far google has only given me results on how to write in a circle or around an embedded image. But not how to make the margin of the page different in size.

The only thing I can think of is to adjust it by hand with spaces, but that would drive people crazy.

Anybody got any ideas?

edit:

The shapes created by shapepar depend on the length of the text contained in it. So I'd need a new shape for each page with a different text.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand\shapeleft{ {25}
{0} b{23.32} \\
{0.1} t{20.87}{15} \\
{17.1} t{13.87}{22} \\
{29.1} t{13.87}{22} \\
{50.4} t{15.87}{20} \\
{50.6} e{20}
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \shapepar{\shapeleft} \blindtext[1]

  \shapepar{\shapeleft} \blindtext[2]
  \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: two shapes with different sizes]

Is there a way to prevent that the shape size depends on the text length leaving the rest of the shape blank?

edit2: Solved by samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz in the comments.

Comment: Can you please make your questions self-contained, e.g. that it will continue to be helpful for future users with the same problem even if external links are no longer available?

Comment: I am not allowed to uploade images. So I hope it is better this way?

Comment: Thanks, much better :) I suggest to have a look at the `shapepar` package. It can do things like https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQxt4.png

Comment: This looks good. Thanks a lot! I will try it and provide feedback afterwards :)

Comment: I had a little deeper look into it and I think it could work, but I couldn't figure out how to do it in two columns. Any ideas for this?

Comment: Maybe two half ellipses

Comment: Two half elipses work, thanks. But I ran into another issue, see edit.

Comment: Maybe `tikz` maybe provide some hints: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/text-shape/

Comment: @Wasitora Filling the complete shape is a feature of shapepar. If this is not what you are looking for the normal `\parshape` macro might be more appropriate. I just found this nice guide: https://www.dickimaw-books.com/software/flowframtk/manual/newstutorial.shtml#sec:news

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.